# How to give different parts of an array, different attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, colors, attr

I want to give different objects of an array different attributes, like color and size.

I have already managed it once in another part of the Code. I made a new array and gave the groups with the same name the same color. But now I can´t make an array that includes all the colors, for I don´t have a specific object. I want to have all years that are <1500 to be blue. And all that are > 1500 red.

```
var paper;
var paperWidth, paperHeight = 0;
var xPos, yPos, radius = 0;
init();

function init() {
  paper = Snap("#svgContainer");
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].circle = paper.circle(0, 0, 1); 

  }
function showJahresZahlen() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 0; i++) {
      xPos = map(data[i].longitude, (0 - 180), 180, 0, paperWidth);
      yPos = paperHeight - map(data[i].latitude, (0 - 90), 90, 0, paperHeight);

//first approach
circleColor = lava;
      function lava() {
        if (data.lastEruption < 100) {
          circleColor = "blue"
        } else if (data.lastEruption > 1000 && data.lastEruption < 1500) {
          circleColor = "red"
       } else {

          circleColor = "orange"
        }
      }
   data[i].circle.animate({

        cx: xPos,
        cy: yPos,

// second approach
        fill: data.lastEruption < 1000 ? "red" : data.lastEruption > 1000 && data.lastEruption < 1500? "blue": "orange",
        opacity: 0.5,
        stroke: "none",
        r: 5,
      }, 50);
    };
  }

// example out of my array 
var data = [
{
    "lastEruption": 1000,
  },
{ "lastEruption": 250,}
....]
```

I don´t have any errors and in the last approach the color that showed up was orange. But why are blue and red not showing up?

Comment: Check your conditions. In first approach you check `data.lastEruption < 100`. Also, looks like when `data.lastEruption` is `1000` it will be orange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function showJahresZahlen() {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 0; i++) {
      xPos = map(data[i].longitude, (0 - 180), 180, 0, paperWidth);
      yPos = paperHeight - map(data[i].latitude, (0 - 90), 90, 0, paperHeight);


        if (data[i].lastEruption < 100) {
          var circleColor = "blue"
        } else if (data[i].lastEruption > 1000 && data.lastEruption < 1500) {
          var circleColor = "red"
        } else {
          var circleColor = "orange"
        }


      data[i].circle.animate({

        cx: xPos,
        cy: yPos,
        fill: circleColor,
      }, 2000);
    };
```

}